# Log4Net Azure Function hide microsoft logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Log4Net within Azure Functions with .net core 3.1.

I am getting multiple unnecessary info microsoft logs like these:

```
Disposing ScriptHost.
Job host stopped
Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener' for function '...'
```

How can I make only errors come out?

I'm configuring appsettings.json and host.json, with these log levels, for system and microsoft configured with "Error", but I keep getting a lot of logs.

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Microsoft.*": "Error"
    }
}
```

It seems this configuration is being ignored, what can I do in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I modifing appsettings.json and host.json with this configuration, and has worked:

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Function.Common.User" : "Debug",
        "Microsoft.*": "Error",
        "Function.*" : "Error",
        "Host.*": "Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).